# Is vibratory motion in straight line also pure translatory motion?

Tags: kinematics, terminology, vibrations

I think pure translatory motion is defined as change in position of the object such that the velocity of each particle of the object is parallel and in the same direction to each other and is of the same magnitude. Suppose an object is vibrating in a straight line, is the motion shown by the object vibratory motion as well as pure translatory motion?

Comment: object is in a harmonic motion in a straight line.

Comment: Yes that would fulfill this definition if all points standing still is considered change in position to you. You are not the only one [looking for a hole in this definition.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/595778/71413)

Comment: Combination of information from the internet and my own understanding.

Comment: what do you mean by"if all points standing still is considered change in position to you"?

Comment: Well if it's vibrating it has to turn around, right? Otherwise, that is what you would consider the "normal" kind of translation and not vibration. So the way your wrote it, vibration really is not included. Sorry for being confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a 1-DOF vibration where only translation is allowed, and there is no coupled  rotation, then yes the velocity vector for all points at all times will be parallel to the same direction vector.

For example if allowed to move along the *x*-axis then

$$ \vec{v} = \pmatrix{1 \\ 0 \\ 0} v $$

where $v=V \sin \omega t$ is the speed at some instant.